# Apps with system title bars and borders open up magnified

Tags: gnome, display, system-settings, 23.04

I have been struggling with an issue recently and I would like to know why it's happening.

I have Ubuntu 23.04 on my laptop. Recently I've noticed an issue that's annoying. Whenever I open certain apps(specifically the apps with system title bar), the apps initially open up magnified and blurry. For example, VLC Media player has a system title bar. Opening it for the first time, it will open up as I mentioned. It is magnified in such a way that if I click the maximize button, the close button is pressed. So I have to manually disable function lock and maximize window using F11.

What would be the issue? any help would be appreciated.

My Laptop is Inspiron 5501, with Intel core i5 and Nvidia MX 330 GPU.